# Which control does MS use in Win 10 Store app?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I've try FlipView but it seem like flipview only show 1 item per time.

I just want to know if there's a existing control before create my own custom control.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pivot control is what you are looking for.

Best of luck !